# Sms Based Authentication

Tags: authentication, login

I  enabled sms based authentication.Then it works in first time when i signed in.But then  it never requires second step for my computer again. It adds the computer in trusted list.How can i accomplish this to ask everytime sms and email based authentication. Also can i make it just  for  the specific profiles ? I mean profile basis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your org go to setup > Administer > Network Access and set the ip range which is do not fall in the ip range of the login user. In this case the user will always be asked for verification code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can i enabled it for profile basis ?

Comment: go to setup > Administer > Profile (Select your profile where you wan to set IP range) > at the bottom u can see the Login IP Ranges their you can set the IP range.